# Comparing Elements Inside an Array

Tags: java, arrays

I am having some trouble comparing elements inside an array. I am creating a poker problem and cannot seem to write code to tell if two elements are the same. This is my code comparing what is in the elements

```
public static boolean pairs() {
    for (int i = currentCard; i < deck.length; i++) {
        for (int j = currentCard ; j < deck.length; j++) {
            if (deck[i] == deck[j])
                return pairs == true;
        }
    }
    return pairs;
}
```

And this is the code that builds the array:

```
public CreateDeck() {
    String[] faces = { "Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six",
        "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };
    String[] suits = { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs" };

    deck = new Card[NUMBER_OF_CARDS];
    currentCard = 0;

    for (int count = 0; count < deck.length; count++)
        deck[count] = new Card(faces[count % 13], suits[count / 13]);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, I have tried many things, and now am just trying things at random. Thanks!

Comment: Here we go again... The 289545th question about Object comparison with == in Java :-)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use and implement Card.equals(Card) instead of ==. (and thus also hashCode(), there are many questions here answering the why).

That would make your pairs() something like this:

```
public static boolean pairs() {
    {
        for (int i = currentCard; i < deck.length; i++) {
            for (int j = currentCard ; j < deck.length; j++) {
                if (i!=j && deck[i].equals(deck[j]))
                    return true;
            }

        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It returns true if and only if the is one deck[i] equals to another deck[j]. false otherwise.

Comment: The deck[i] and deck[j] and not string, they are Card objects, so they'll need to implement .equals

Comment: Indeed. I'm quite confused why this seems to be accepted by the community. I don't remember Java very well, but won't this just call `Object.equals()` which... is (close to?) what he's already doing.

Comment: How do I compare if any of the Objects match, it doesn't have to be all of them? I just want to find if there is one pair

Answer (score 0):

Right, so the items in your deck array are different Card objects. the == operator compares *pointers*, so they are different for different objects. If you are trying to compare the *values* of the Card objects, you need to implements an equals method (overriding the one inherited from Object) and the call deck[i].equals(deck[j]).